# Utility bar component refresh

Tags: lightning-aura-components, utility-bar

We have a lightning cmp. as a utility bar item.
This cmp. is showing a list view of leads.
When a lead in the list is clicked the lead opens in the main area.
I want to have the utility bar cmp. refresh if an update is made to the lead, specifically I want the list view to auto refresh to not show this lead anymore, if it does not meet the filter condition.

Can the utility bar cmp. auto refresh based on a change of a record in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have CDC (Change Data Capture), you can subscribe to changes to Leads in your component, and when you detect a change, you can refresh the list. Alternatively, you can also use the Streaming API to subscribe to a push topic for leads, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/pushtopic_queries.htm). You just need to use the lightning:empApi (Aura) or pubsub module (LWC).

Comment: I was hoping for something native. Can CDC be used internally or only with External Objects?

Comment: @Dedo Yes, CDC works internally.