# Aura component is loading only for first time from utility Item

Tags: aura

I'm calling aura component from utility bar. On click of utility item for the first time it is loading and opening the aura component(from there using workspaceAPI.openTab & url as parameter ). When we close this tab and click on the utility item for second time it is not loading.(I'm using aura handler in cmp file. Tried with both init & render, still able to open only for first time). Can anyone please help, how can we open the aura cmp from utility item any number of times.

Comment: It will be better to add the code snippet. From the description it will be hard to help. Which interfaces are you using

Answer (score 0):

Currently, It is a limitation and idea has been raised here which you can upvote:- [Option to refresh utility bar list view every time it's opened](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddlsUAB/option-to-refresh-utility-bar-list-view-every-time-its-opened)

As a workaround, I would suggest going for these:-

1. Adding a custom refresh button in your aura component and reload your component by handling onclick
2. Check if CDC or Streaming API works in your use case - [Utility bar component refresh](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302101/utility-bar-component-refresh)